# IntelliJ code not recognizing font files even though it is clear they exist

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, javafx-8

IntelliJ/Java is not recognizing a file that is clearly there. Here is my filesystem:

```
MODULE/resources/a.ttf
MODULE/resources/test.png
MODULE/src/test/Test.java
```

Here is the code I am using: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/pQxRXMF3wg/

Which part of my code is incorrect, and how do I fix it?

### What I've done:

- Marked my  directory as a resources root.
- Made sure the resources actually exist.
- Tried this: 'getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/a.ttf");'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was actually quite simple actually, as it had something to do with @KolyaSh's comment. After decompiling my JAR, I found that the 'resources' folder was never actually put into the JAR file, thus my code not working in the first place. Another issue was the way I was trying to retrieve the resource URL. I tried `ClassLoader.getSystemResource()`, though I researched more upon why that wouldn't be the solution.

The solution was to get the calling class's ClassLoader. I also wrote a method to read the file, which looked something like this:

```
Font.loadFont(getResource("a.ttf"), doubleValue);
/* NOTE: The string argument in the resource is the path of which the 
file is located. If your file path is something like 
'resources/fonts/a.ttf', please use 'fonts/a.ttf' as the string argument.
*/
public InputStream getResource(String path) {
  URL url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(path);
  try {
    URLConnection c = url.openConnection();
    return c.getInputStream();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

To give a straight answer, the concept I was missing was how the File was actually stored in the jar, and on how to access it. First, you must get the ClassLoader instance (don't use the static methods it provides), open a connection to the URL path, get the InputStream, and voila, you have yourself a nice, simple way to load any file from inside a compiled JAR.

Thanks again to all those who helped answer this question!! Hope this clears everything up.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following steps:

1. Right mouse click on resource package (in IntelliJ) -> Mark Directory as -> Resources Root.
2. Now you files should be able to access by "test.png" instead of "resources/test.png".

Hope this gonna help.

Have fun! =)

Comment: I edited my post with some extra information that way I don't get answers that I've already done. I've already marked the directory as a resources root.

Comment: As I mentioned in the 2nd step, try getClass().getResourceAsStream("a.ttf"); or File file = new File("a.ttf"); System.out.println(file.exists()); - true should be printed in the console

Comment: Quick question! Does 'getClass().getResourceAsStream("a.ttf") access the file from anywhere in my jar file? So if it was in /resources/fonts/a.ttf it would be the same method?

Comment: If resources folder is your Resources Root (step 1), you should ask "fonts/a.ttf" to get access to the file under /resources/fonts/a.ttf

Comment: Will using the File class also work when compiling into a JavaFX Application or Jar?

Comment: I tried your method, and getting the same result. The code in the post is what I use currently. If possible, could you provide an example of a resource folder and src folder separate, with a class accessing a resource in the folder? I'd like to see an example to edit my code with.

Comment: You can try another check: if your file a.ttf is in resources package, do File file = new File("a.ttf");  Then CTRL + left mouse click on "a.ttf" - if IntelliJ will open this file, that code works fine. It is seemed to me, that your problem is because of jar-building project (I see, that you don't use Maven, so, maybe, you build your projects manually, so the issue happens during some wrong steps/actions during the build process - but for this another topic should be created).

Comment: I've added my own solution to this @KolyaSh and I used the concepts you suggested. One thing that didn't work though is using the File object. In my research, I found that the files are no longer physical files when compiled, so I needed to access them using the InputStream object. Another thing though was that I can't use the class's `getResource()` method. I needed to use the class's ClassLoader's `getResource()` method. Other than those minor changes, your comments really gave some insight on how to resolve this issue. Thanks for your help!